# How to import a folder full of pictures, one per page, alphabetically in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, batch-processing, script, data-merge

I'm trying to import a folder full of pictures (bar codes), one per page in alphabetical order into InDesign.

I've found the following link which shows how to create a script that will turn the images into a CSV file which I can then data merge into InDesign.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AfDojdhILig

The problem I'm having is that the script creates a CSV file but the images aren't listed in alphabetical order. I'm assuming there might be a default where they are imported by file size. If I reorder the images alphabetically in the CSV file the data merge changes from 'images' to 'text'. I would normally just import the images one by one but on this occasion, I have 5,000 (numbered SPA200001 to SPA205001).

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need a script for this.

Just running this command in your particular folder using the command prompt ('cmd') in Windows will generate that list for you, alphabetically.

```
dir /on /b >> list.csv
```

It will just be a plain text file in this format:

```
image 1

image 2

image 3

... 

image 5000
```

Then, add this at the top of that text file:

```
@image
```

Then, setup and import using Data Merge as seen in most tutorials.

Comment: Thanks but I'm on a Mac platform.

Comment: Then, you can probably buy an app that can do this for you :)) Kidding. See this and try until it works https://osxdaily.com/2013/01/29/list-all-files-subdirectory-contents-recursively/

Comment: Great info on the dos command. Only drawback was that the list.csv name was included in the list.

Comment: Yes, that does happen, but easy to remove in a text editor. With Data Merge there is always some degree of manually adjusting the data before merging.